# Order or loading within contextConfigLocation in web.xml of Spring Servlet project

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

In a spring-servlet web application, if there are multiple context xmls under contextConfigLocation, is it guaranteed that these context files will be loaded in the same order in which they are specified?

**Sample web.xml:**

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        a.xml
        b.xml
        c.xml
      </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In the above sample web.xml, is it guaranteed that the beans in a.xml will be loaded before loading beans in b.xml, provided there is no other dependency(through injection or "depends-on") specified?